# Why does URL("http://pboss.pozit.pl/contact.html").readText() make android app crash?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

That is a fragment of my MainActivity.kt file.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    message.text=URL("http://pboss.pozit.pl/contact.html").readText()
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
}
```

The app is working with just plain text instead of `URL("http://pboss.pozit.pl/contact.html").readText()` but is crashing with the following code.
I already added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to the mainfest.

Note: `URL("http://pboss.pozit.pl/contact.html").readText()` is the only edited thing in whole app.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Android doesn't allow synchronous requests in the UI thread. That's _probably_ why the app crashes. Use an async approach, like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) with its StringRequest class.

Comment: I used `val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)` for now. I know, that it is not the best solution but since what I'm doing is just experimental it is OK. Thanks a lot guys.